# Modelling a problem with a System of Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Here is the formulation:

> A network consisting of two power supply stations denoted by $S_1$ and
>   $S_2$ and five power recipient nodes denoted by $N_1$ : $N_5$. The nodes are connected by power lines, $f_1$ : $f_7$, which are denoted by arrows, and power can flow between nodes along these lines in both
>   directions.

[image]

> Let $d_i$ be a positive scalar denoting the power demands for node $i$, and assume that this demand must be met exactly. The capacity of the power supply stations is denoted by $S$. Power supply stations must run at their capacity. For each arrow, let $f_j$ be the power flow along that arrow. Negative flow implies that power is running in the opposite direction of the arrow.

Given $S_1$, $S_2$ and $N_1$ : $N_5$, find a $f_1$ : $f_7$.

Here is how I try to tackle it:

I'm constructing a system of linear equations where each node ($S$ or $N_i$) is on the r.h.s. and the flows ($f_i$) are on the l.h.s:

$$-f_3 + f_4 - f_6 = N_1$$

$$f_5 - f_7 = N_2$$

$$...$$

$$f_6 + f_7 = N_5$$

$$-f_1 = S_1$$

$$-f_4 - f_5 = S_2$$

then I rewrite the above in a matrix form, where the l.h.s is the matrix $A$:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 1 &  0 &-1 \\
    \dots  \\
    0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 1 \\ 
    -1 & 0 &  0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 &  0 & -1 & -1 &  0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}

the r.h.s is a column vector $b$:

\begin{bmatrix}
    N_1 \\
    N_2 \\
    \dots  \\
    N_5\\ 
    S_1 \\ 
    S_2\\ 
\end{bmatrix}

so, finding the values of $f_i$ is solving the system in the matrix form $Af = b$. However, the current system fails to reproduce few test cases, like: $S_1 = 10, S_2 = 10, N_1 : N_5 = 4$, instead of getting: $f_1 = 10, f_2 = 4, f_3 = -2, f_4 = 4.5, f_5 = 5.5, f_6 = 2.5, f_7 = 1.5$, I get no solutions.

What am I doing wrong?

How to represent the stated problem as a system of linear equations?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your well-chosen approach is known as [Kirchhoff's Current Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws):

> *At any node (junction) in an electrical circuit, the sum of currents flowing into that node is equal to the sum of currents flowing out of that node.*

The signs in the bottom two rows of your matrix have to be reversed, because power supply stations are counted in the opposite direction than power recipients.

$f_1$ is equal to the absolute value of $S_1$.

The sum of $f_4$ and $f_5$ is the absolute value of $S_2$

As an alternative, you could use opposite signs for source quantities and consumption quantities.

Comment: The flow from a source vs flow from a sink, it makes sense, and I got the wanted results, thank you!